# Smaller program to take click input of mouse from multiple JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, actionevent

I have a bunch of labels in a single frame which basically serves as a multi-line output for displaying text. At certain points of the program the user needs select a option from a given choices. The way they do this is by clicking on the appropriate JLabel.

I tried with a JLabel array, but the functions do not work. I then made a separate ActionEvent for each JLabel, which works, but is there a elegant or efficient code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre welcome.

you described your problem and i think i can follow.

you could figure out the similarites the `ActionListener`s have and put those similarities into a `super`-`Class`

for me, another possibility seems to be an 'all-in-one' `ActionListener`. its `actionPerformed`-Method has got a paramter of type `ActionEvent`. this `ActionEvent` provides a `getSource()`-Method, you can retrieve the `JComponent` the `ActionEvent` occured on. so if you give names to your `JLabel`s, you can check for the name(s) in the `actionPerformed`-Method

**Edit**

like this way:

```
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    final String name = ((JComponent) actionEvent.getSource()).getName();
    switch (name) {
        case "label1":
            handleLabel1();
            break;
        case "label2":
            handleLabel2();
            break;
        case "label3":
            handleLabel3();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Application extends JFrame {
    private abstract class MyComponentListener implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
        protected void actionOnButton(final AWTEvent e) {
            final JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
            switch (button.getName()) {
                case "button1":
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("mouse button one clicked on " + button.getName());
                    break;
            }
            // more general
            this.actionOnComponent(e);
        }

        protected void actionOnComponent(final AWTEvent e) {
            final JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            final int index = Integer.valueOf(component.getName().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")).intValue();
            switch (index) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("mouse button one clicked on " + component.getName());
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void actionOnLabel(final AWTEvent e) {
            final JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            switch (label.getName()) {
                case "label1":
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("mouse button one clicked on " + label.getName());
                    break;
            }
            // more general
            this.actionOnComponent(e);
        }
    }

    private class MyListener extends MyComponentListener {
        /**
         * {@link ActionListener#actionPerformed(ActionEvent)}
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("next line(s) generated by ActionListener");
            this.actionOnButton(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
            // whole process of mouse button down and up
            if ((e.getButton() == 1)) {
                System.out.println("next line(s) generated by MouseListener");
                if ((e.getSource() instanceof JLabel)) {
                    this.actionOnLabel(e);
                } else if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                    this.actionOnButton(e);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(final MouseEvent e) {
            // on mouse over
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(final MouseEvent e) {
            // on mouse out
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            // mouse button down
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {
            // mouse button up after down
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Application() {
        super();
    }

    public void start() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        this.addLabel("Hello World - Label", "label1");
        this.addLabel("Label 2", "label2");
        this.addLabel("Label 3", "label3");
        this.addButton("Hello Word - Button", "button1");
        this.addButton("Button 2", "button2");
        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(500, 150);
        this.setSize(dimension);
        this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addButton(final String text, final String name) {
        final JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setName(name);
        button.addMouseListener(new MyListener());
        button.addActionListener(new MyListener());
        this.getContentPane().add(button);
    }

    private void addLabel(final String text, final String name) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setName(name);
        label.addMouseListener(new MyListener());
        this.getContentPane().add(label);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Application app = new Application();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                app.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris!  Thanks for your reply. So I tweaked around the code and got the all labels replaced with a JLabel Array. can you tell me how your code will change accordingly. Also itll be swell if you could type out the exact syntax too. you see im not exactly a expert in java (heck i wont even call myself a amature). like where do i put the mouseAdapter function and the mouse listener functions??.   Thanks a lot!